# Groovy: Ternary operator says that "" is null

Tags: groovy, null, ternary-operator

```
def nullString = "String is NOT null"

def check = (nullString != null) ? nullString : "String is null"
def check2 = nullString ? nullString : "String is null"
def check3 = nullString ?: "String is null"

println check 
println check2
println check3
```

Tell me if I'm wrong, but these three  ternary statements above should all do the same thing, namely print out "String is NOT null" if nulString is not null. If nullString is null, print out "String is null".

And I think you all agree, if I initialze a variable like *nullString = ""* it is not null. Just because "" is not null.

But when testing the code above with *nullString = ""* only the first one prints out "String is NOT null". The other two interpret "" as null. Why is that?

(Sorry for my english, I hope you understand what I'm trying to say)

Comment: Ternary doesn't check for null, it checks for truthfulness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The empty string is falsy in Groovy.](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)

Comment: This is now a broken link

Comment: @PedroA Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Empty string evaluates to false by default, this evaluates to true:

```
assert !""
```